# Audacity vs MATLAB/pyhton for basic signal processing concepts?

Tags: matlab, python, teaching

[Use of "Audacity"for teaching undergraduate labs of digital signal processing for electrical engineering students?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/83730/use-of-audacityfor-teaching-undergraduate-labs-of-digital-signal-processing-fo)

My above realted linked question has got some good answers.

Traditionally MATLAB and python are used for signal processing teaching but i want to know for case of basic/entry level so as to motivate students towards field of signal processing as many students consider signal processing to be complex and boring. If at the intial level,their interest is build up using  basic signal processing operations in Audacity,it will be easy to motivate them. According to my understanding audacity is much easier than MATLAB and python in this regard. Because when students are exposed to any application of signal processing in audacity like filtering,it may also possibly attract their motivation for studying signal processing

Comment: Nyquist programming language is maybe not the widest supported DSP language ... so, in the future, your students may face difficulties in working world when employer points them to use Matlab, Python or some other more common language for their job tasks.

Comment: You’ve basically asked the same question a year ago. Or is there a major difference?